# How to connect node app to node api with Nginx

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nginx, ufw

I built a Node app using [this tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/10/29/angular-7-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial). Then I built a Node API using [this tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/14/nodejs-mongodb-simple-api-for-authentication-registration-and-user-management). The app uses the app on `port 4000` to connect to the API which then connects to a `mongodb` to store the info on the server.

This setup works great on my local machine, but I'm trying to deploy it on a digital ocean `droplet`. I have `Nginx` setup to listen to `port 8080` for the main app. I'm able to navigate to the app. But when I try to register a user and submit the data to the API I get the following error in my browser `OPTIONS http://localhost:4000/users/register net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I suspect I have to specify something in the Nginx config files. Or would it be a `ufw` issue? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very clear. The application try to fetch on `localhost:4000`, so you expect any visitor of your web app to have the API launched on their own computer.

Change your code to point to the correct host and port of you server.

Then, as you guess it, you will have to create a little Nginx configuration to tell him what to proxy to the APP and what to proxy to the API.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The API is running on the same droplet, so it should still be running as localhost. When I test the API locally I access it via  `localhost:4000`. So shouldn't my node app still be able to connect there? And I'd rather not open the API up to the public, but have only my app connect. So do I still need to an Nginx config?

Comment: I gave you the answer, the fetch request executed, from angular code, in your browser, to localhost is the mistake. Unless you expect any visitor to run API on their own PC. Change it to the same url as the one you use to connect to the webapp, add '/api' as basepath then comeback for the nginx configuration.

Comment: It was taking me a bit to wrap my brain around that. But it makes sense now and I have it up and running. Thanks for the help